# How can I set Max date to 7th day from today in input type date?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

document.getElementsByName("DateOfTravel")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

With the help of this I am able to set *min* date to today date but now I want to set *max* date to 7th date from today's date

Answer (score 1):

You can write following code.

```
<input type="date" id="datePickerId" />

var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);

datePickerId.max = date.toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
var today = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("DateOfTravel")[0].setAttribute('max', today);
```